# Is mandatory to select the option of PromptDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, bots

If we choose the PromptDialog then the option of PromptDialog must be selected. Is it mandatory to select the option?

Without selecting the option and the user asks for a new query as well as Bot will response according to the new query.

In simple, how do we ignore without select option and take the new request and provide the answer to the user by Bot?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called **user interruptions**, what happens is every time a user sends a message to your bot, the first thing you will check is that if its an "**interruption**" of an ongoing dialog, or it's a totally new message.

If it's an interruption, you can handle it, you can start a new dialog, finish and then continue where the user left off.

Check the Bot Service Docs here for [Handling User Interruption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches for this :

**Approach 1:** Use ['Handle Interruptions'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), but it comes with a cost. It will check so for all messages sent by user whether in or out of a dialog/prompt. 
Any useful input entered for any text prompt could match any case in switch, which might end that conversation there itself.
Also, it could slow down the process

**Approach 2:** (If you want to do this only for a choice prompt) There is a validation function that can be attached to any kind of prompt.

Suppose `CheckChoicePromptValidator`is your choice prompt validator. You can do something like this inside it:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckChoicePromptValidator(PromptValidatorContext<FoundChoice> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(promptContext.Recognized.Succeeded)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            var userInput = promptContext.Context.Activity.Text;
            // You can use LUIS instead of switch case
            switch(userInput.ToLower())
            {
                case "cancel":
                case "quit":
                case "reset":
                    await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Cancelling!"), cancellationToken);
                    var dc = await BotUtil.Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(promptContext.Context, cancellationToken);
                    await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
                    return await Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }

    }
```

It will only handle the interruptions when user enters something other than choices.

Comment: Thank you so much and it is useful for me

Comment: @AshwiniKumar, you can accept the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!